# asdf-nodejs fails to build nodejs 8.16.0

Tags: node.js, asdf

I keep getting this error somehow. At first I was getting errors that python 2.7 was missing so I installed it and added it to path. I followed the guide on asdf website but somehow I still messed something up.

```
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/node-build.20220505011022.4204.OJD33j
Results logged to /tmp/node-build.20220505011022.4204.log

Last 10 log lines:
                 'v8_optimized_debug': 0,
                 'v8_promise_internal_field_count': 1,
                 'v8_random_seed': 0,
                 'v8_trace_maps': 0,
                 'v8_use_snapshot': 'true',
                 'want_separate_host_toolset': 0}}
creating config.gypi
creating config.mk
Error running GYP
gyp: name 'llvm_version' is not defined while evaluating condition '(OS=="win" and MSVS_VERSION>="2012") or llvm_version>="3.3" or xcode_version>="5.0" or gas_version>="2.23"' in deps\openssl\openssl.gyp while loading dependencies of node.gyp while trying to load node.gyp
```

Comment: Please stop trying this and use one of the LTS versions of Node, which are currently v16 and v18 =) Node 8 is _more than several years_ past dead... as is Python 2.7: both reached EOL years ago and neither should ever be used for new projects. (and old projects that relied on them got uplifted years ago)